# Understanding R - is.na and blank "" cells

Tags: r, excel, missing-data

I have a dataset.  Previous to a lot of different file manipulations, many cells were "NA"

After the manipulations, for whatever reason, they have all become just purely empty.  So, to be clear, the SAME cells that were previously NA in excel now just show up totally blank.  No big deal, right?

Well, when I read the data into R I get...

```
 [1] ""                  ""                  "6.4019975396e+17" 
 [4] ""                  ""                  ""                 
 [7] ""                  ""                  "6.40275087015e+17"
[10] "6.4062774821e+17"  ""                  "6.40602341e+17"   
[13] ""                  ""                  "6.40360673735e+17"
[16] "6.40326194081e+17" "6.40326465381e+17" "6.40322363352e+17"
```

Still seems fine to me, except when I run

is.na(data_frame$column_name)

I get ALL FALSE.  Every single one.  Am I misunderstanding how is.na works?

EDIT - This was kind of vague. Of course I am misunderstanding how it works.  Can you explain why an empty cell does not count as an NA cell?  Is there a quick-fix that can be applied to a data frame to make anything that is "" or what would be a blank cell in a CSV to NA for R's sake?

Comment: How did you read the data in?

Comment: Also, they are all character, not numeric.

Comment: I read the data in with read.csv(file_name, colClasses="character").  To clarify again, in Excel the cells are BLANK.  They previously were the letters NA but after much shuffling of data from various files they are now blank.  This is fine for me, if I can get R to work with it.

Comment: Try just `read.csv(file_name, na.strings = c("", "NA"))`.  Not sure why you chose to have character columns, but either way the `na.strings` argument will produce the `NA` values

Comment: This read.csv(file_name, na.strings = c("", "NA")) method worked beautifully.  Achieving expected results now.  Thanks a lot, sir.

Answer (score 10):

> Can you explain why an empty cell does not count as an NA cell?

I think, in short, the answer is that to R `NA` and empty `""` are different. The *why* of it is that `""` is a blank, and `NA` is something that is truly missing---you have no idea what it is, it could be anything.

To replace blanks with `NA`, post-hoc, for a single column you could do

```
data$column[data$column == ""] <- NA
```

To do that for all columns in a data frame

```
data = lapply(data, function(x) {x[x == ""] <- NA})
```

As pointed out in comments, the best time to address the problem is when you read the data in, with the `na.strings` argument of `read.csv` or `read.table`.

```
read.csv(file_name, na.strings = c("", "NA"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe not only R but in general programming languages also treat empty "" and NA (in some null) as differently.

*NA* is the value where nothing was provided or value is assigned.
*""* empty is a string value. that means there is an empty string.

I just found one interesting article about looking at a dataset, you can look at summaries of columns of a dataset in one go http://www.bytefold.com/generate-metadata-for-a-dataset-in-r/

Comment: Thanks, @GregorThomas! Updated my statement.