# Is third value in the vector y <- c("abc", "def", "", "ghi") is NULL, NA or something else?

Tags: r

So the function `na_if(y, "")` can change the third value in `y <- c("abc", "def", "", "ghi")` to NA ( missing value ), but what actually this third value is? is it missing value, or NULL or something else? And which function to use to check this?

Comment: It's a blank character string. You can use `stringr::str_length(y) == 0` to detect it.

Comment: Or just `!nzchar(y)` ...

Comment: Its the number of characters. So try doing `nchar(y)` it should count the number of characters in each of the elements in `y`. `""` is a character of length 0

Answer (score 2):

`NA`, `NULL`, and `""` are all different in `R`.

`""` is the empty string. You can check for it using `x == ""`. `NA` is something that does not exist. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556967/understanding-r-is-na-and-blank-cells) for more info.

From the `R` documentation:

```
NA   : is generally interpreted as a missing, does not exist
NULL : is for empty object.
```

You can check for `NA` using `is.na`. Similarly, check for `NULL` using `is.null`.

Read more about `NA` vs `NULL` [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2010/04/r-na-vs-null/amp/).